# Multiple arguments in a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scopes

This is probably simple for most of you out there, I however havent really written many scopes that have multiple arguments, single arguments are fine, just unsure here. I am trying to create a scope that says "Give me all the books that the current user has checked out"

So I have come up with this in my book model

```
scope :checked_out_book, lambda{|user| { :conditions => { :user_id => current_user.id, :checked_out => true } }
```

Haven’t used lambda before so unsure if i am using it correctly, either way i am getting the error

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting '}'
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction

EDIT

Have changed scope to

```
scope :checked_out_book, lambda {|user| where(:user_id => user.id, :checked_out => true) }
```

but now i get

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
Thanks

Comment: oh yes, i missed the { before user so didnt close it, silly error

Comment: mark as answer if you wish, will accept if you wouldnt mind explaining a litte about lambda and why we pass user in the || thank you

Comment: And this has nothing to do with your question but your scope is false, current_user won't give you anything here, you should use the given `user` argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
scope :checked_out_book, lambda {|user| where(:user_id => user.id, :checked_out => true) }
```

Comment: this may be a silly question but is that why im passing |user|, im not to sure on the use of lambda at the moment, thank you for your answer though

Comment: solved that one, missing ) at end, now getting wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Comment: You have to pass a user to the scope:    `Book.checked_out_book(@some_user)`

Comment: ah right, so in my case current_user as it will change dependent upon who is logged in

Answer (score 1):

```
scope :checked_out_book, lambda {|user| where(:user_id => user.id, :checked_out => true) }
```

Answer (score 1):

On the `Book` model, the scope should be like this:

```
scope :checked_out_book, lambda {|user| where(:user_id => user.id, :checked_out => true) }
```

or for Ruby 1.9

```
scope :checked_out_book, ->(user) { where(user_id: user.id, checked_out: true) }
```

And you would call it like this:

```
Book.checked_out_book(current_user)
```

Now since `User` has_many `Books`, I would probably go with something like this and don't bother with scopes. If you want a method like approach, you can always create a method that returns a `Relation` object.

```
current_user.books.where(checked_out: true)
```

or

```
def checked_out_books
  books.where(checked_out: true)
end
# current_user.checked_out_books
```

Comment: thanks, thats nice, any reason why not using scopes is better here? just wondering from an educational point of view

Comment: It's just a matter of personal preference I guess. In Rails 2 they allowed you to chain queries, but since almost everything in Rails 3 returns a Relation object, you can chain it too and scopes become just a weird way to write class methods...